# To check edit permission on a specific list using ecma script client object model

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, javascript, client-object-model

Users will have read permission at web level but in some scenario few users can have edit permission on just one list under the web (role is broken for the list and explicit permission is given on the list for specific users)

Is it possible to check if a particular user has edit permission on just that list using ecma script client object model.

If i try to use `permissionsToCheck.set(SP.PermissionKind.editListItems);` on the web object, the api returns false. I believe the behavior is so, as user has read permission on web and all lists, doc lib except for one list where he has edit permission

EDIT:
Thanks steve ... this is how I got it work
(Disclaimer: This is not the actual tested code, I just wanted to highlight the part where we are requesting EffectiveBasePermissions explicitly ie., this line `clientContext.load(list, 'EffectiveBasePermissions');`

```
function foo(){
            ...
var list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Notes');
           clientContext.load(list);
           clientContext.load(list, 'EffectiveBasePermissions');   
           clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, bar), Function.createDelegate(this, onFailureToRetrieve));   
}

function bar(){
    var perm = this.discussionList.get_effectiveBasePermissions();
    alert( perm.has(SP.PermissionKind.editListItems) );
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you just need to get a reference to the list object.  Here is a link to a blog post that might help:  [Using the SharePoint 2010 Client Object Model – Part 5](http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2009/11/01/using-the-sharepoint-2010-client-object-model-part-5.aspx).